# Why I can't use inheritance's error as SFINAE?

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, sfinae

I have this code, but it does not compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cassert>


template< class > struct id{};
template< class U, class V> struct base: public id<U>, public id<V>
{
    static const bool value = true;
};

template< class U, class V>
struct is_different
{

  typedef char (&true_)[1];
  typedef char (&false_)[2];

  template< class T, class K, bool  = base<T,K>::value >
  struct checker;



  template< class T, class K>
  static true_  test( checker<T,K>* );

  template< class , class >
  static false_  test(...);


  static const bool value = sizeof( test<U,V>(0) ) == sizeof(true_);

};


int main (void) 
{
    bool b1 = is_different<int,float>::value;
    bool b2 = is_different<int,int>::value; // <--- error

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << b1 << '\n'
                                << b2  << '\n';
    return 0;       
}
```

error:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘struct base<int, int>’:
main.cpp:25:17:   required by substitution of ‘template<class T, class K> static char (& is_different<U, V>::test(is_different<U, V>::checker<T, K>*))[1] [with T = T; K = K; U = int; V = int] [with T = int; K = int]’
main.cpp:31:41:   required from ‘const bool is_different<int, int>::value’
main.cpp:39:38:   required from here
main.cpp:7:36: error: duplicate base type ‘id<int>’ invalid
 template< class U, class V> struct base: public id<U>, public id<V>
```

Why I can't use duplicate inheritance's failure as SFINAE?

Comment: I'd say because template argument substitution doesn't neccesarily involve instantiating a template class, which would be required to detect inheritance from same types. SFINAE would be inconsistent it that were part of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SFINAE only applies to things directly within the function signature. The compilation error you get happens within the instantiation of `base<T, K>`, which is two steps removed from the function signature.

That said, why do you do this the hard way?

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct is_same { static const bool value = false; };

template <typename T>
struct is_same<T, T> { static const bool value = true; };

template <typename T, typename U>
struct is_different { static const bool value = !is_same<T, U>::value; };
```

**Edit:**

So, to answer your question in the comment, let me explain a bit more about SFINAE. The standard specifies SFINAE in 17.8.2p8:

> If a substitution results in an invalid type or rexpression, type deduction fails. An invalid type or rexpression is one that would be ill-formed if written using the substituted arguments. Only invalid types and expressions in the immediate context of the function type and its template parameter types can result in a deduction failure. [*Note:* The evaluation of the substituted types and expressions can result in side effects such as the instantiation of the class template specializations and/or function template specializations, the generation of implicitly-defined functions, et. Such side effects are not in the "immediate context" and can result in the program being ill-formed. - *end note*]

The thing that's problematic here is the "immediate context". You are doing two things here that remove your error from the immediate context.

- The error occurs during evaluation of the default argument expression of `checker`. Although this evaluation is triggered by the occurrence of `checker<T,K>` in the argument list of `test`, which gets instantiated for overload resolution, it isn't the immediate context. You can try this out by changing the definition of `base` to `template <typename T, typename U> struct base {};`. This makes the error in the instantiation of `base` go away, replacing it with an error in the context of the default argument expression ("does not have a member called `value`"). But SFINAE will still not trigger; you'll still get a hard error.
- The error occurs in the instantiation of the definition of `base`. This is yet another step removed from overload resolution. For the same reason, putting a member into `base` with type `T::foobar` doesn't work for finding out whether `T` contains a type `foobar`: the definition of `base` is not a SFINAE context anymore. You can see that this alone is an error by removing `checker` from the picture, e.g. doing this:

```
template <typename U, typename V> struct base: public id<U>, public id<V> {
    typedef void type;
};
template <typename U, typename V> struct is_different {
  struct true_ { char c[1]; };  // I don't like sizeof(reference type),
  struct false_ { char c[2]; }; // makes me nervous.
  template <typename T, typename K>
  static true_ test(typename base<T, K>::type*);
  template <typename, typename>
  static false_ test(...);

  static const bool value = sizeof(test<U, V>(0)) == sizeof(true_);
};
```

Now the `base` instantiation doesn't hide behind a template default argument expression, but is right there in the signature, but you'll still get an error.

Comment: Could you show another example as above ?  i.e. which SFINAE is not worked. For me not interesting how implemented is_same, is_different or something other, I am interesting only  SFINAE rule which I couldn't use inheritance failure.

Comment: Added a thorough explanation.