# Missing something on SFINAE (dummy template argument form)

Tags: templates, visual-c++, c++17, sfinae

I’m using Visual Studio 17.7 preview 3, and including Boost 1.67.0b1.

I’m an old hand at using `enable_if`, but today I’m trying to use the new way of doing things — a dummy extra template parameter.

Boost.Range does not provide a “is this a range” check, so I’m using [`range_value<X>::value`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0_beta1/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/concept_implementation/semantics/metafunctions.html) as the dependent type does not exist if the nominated type is not a range.  That’s exactly what SFINAE is all about!  The template can’t parse the declaration when I give it a `double`, so it should drop out of the overload set with no error.

```
#include <boost/range/value_type.hpp>


class Fizzer_t {
public:
    using itemdef_t = std::pair<int, std::string_view>;
private:
    std::vector<itemdef_t> playdef;
public:
    template<typename R,
        typename = typename boost::range_value<R>::type>  // only call if R is a "range"
    Fizzer_t (const R & range_of_itemdefs);
    Fizzer_t (double);  // dummy
};

void play2 {
    Fizzer_t player3{ 3.14 };
}
```

When I give it a valid parameter, it does compile.
When I give it a `double`, rather than matching the other constructor it complains that

> 'type': is not a member of 'boost::range_iterator'

which is most decidedly *not* SFINAE.

---

What am I missing here?

Comment: Here's a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19516159/2640636

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with how `boost::range_value` class is defined.

```
namespace boost
{
    template< class T >
    struct range_value : iterator_value< typename range_iterator<T>::type >
    { };
}
```

So, when the compiler gets down to the line in your code where you have

```
typename = typename boost::range_value<R>::type
```

it's not that `boost::range_value<R>` fails to have a `type` member `typedef`, but the `boost::range_value<R>` fails to be a valid type, because it can't inherit from `iterator_value< typename range_iterator<T>::type >`, since that one fails as well.

Hence the original error:

```
error: no type named 'type' in 'struct boost::range_iterator<double, void>'
```

A quick fix would be to just write

```
typename = typename boost::range_value<R>
```

e.i. remove the `::type` at the end. Or, you could check directly whether the `boost::range_iterator<R>` has a `type` member,

```
typename = typename boost::range_iterator<R>::type
```